# Pentaho - раскраска столбиков диаграммы (CCC BAR)

Tags: диаграммы, аналитика

Подскажите как раскрасить столбики диаграммы в зависимости от значения меры?
Предполагаю что должны использоваться поля Color Role, Color Transform компонента "CCC Bar Chart" но не нашел примеров и описания.

Нашел упоминание здесь --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528309/pentaho-cde-conditional-formatting-of-bubble-chart  , но в "CCC Bar Chart" нет поля "colorMap"

создал набор данных содержащий столбец, в котором есть поле возвращающее некий индекс  цвета "1", "2" ... Как применить при отсутствии поля "colorMap" в "CCC Bar Chart".

Answer (score 0):

colorMap отсутствует в свойствах компонента, но в свойство Pre Execution можно добавить данный код и все будет работать. В Вашем случае потребуется наверное добавить данную функцию в свойство Post Fetch компонента.

```
function preExec() {
  $.extend(this.chartDefinition, {
      colorMap: {
          "Ошибка": '#FFD725',
          "Неисправно": '#FF5454',
          "Недоступно": '#BEBEBE',
      }
  });                                                                       
}
```